# Unable to attach my existing EBS volume (data drive) to a newly launched EC2 instance (RHEL 8) through user data commands

Tags: amazon-ec2

Unable to attach my existing EBS volume (data drive) to a newly launched EC2 instance (RHEL 8) through user data commands. I am able to attach the EBS volume manually by connecting the server through putty and using the same set of commands, but not through user data input.

1) Launched a free tier RHEL instance and attached an EBS volume - X (data 
    drive) to it through AWS Web console. The volume X is expected to store 
    few application data.

2) Connected EC2 instance through putty and checked Volume X was visible to 
    the OS. 
>

> #fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvdf: 11 GiB, 11811160064 bytes, 23068672 sectors

3) Formatted/partitioned the drive as below 
>

> #/sbin/mkfs -t ext3 /dev/xvdf

4) Created a directory to mount the volume.

> #mkdir /mnt/data

5) Updated /etc/fstab to make sure that the mount is available even after 
    server reboot. Below is the fstab entry I did.

> #vi /etc/fstab
>
> /dev/xvdf /mnt/data ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0

6) Reboot.

7)   #df -h
>

> ```
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> devtmpfs        391M     0  391M   0% /dev
>
> tmpfs           410M     0  410M   0% /dev/shm
>
> tmpfs           410M   11M  400M   3% /run
>
> tmpfs           410M     0  410M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>
> /dev/xvda2       10G  1.1G  9.0G  11% /
>
> /dev/xvdf        11G   28M   11G   1% /IIG  --> New mount point listed. 
>
> tmpfs            82M     0   82M   0% /run/user/1000
> ```

8) Installed aws cli and configured it as below

> $ sudo yum install -y python3
>
> install aws cli
>
> $ pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
>
> $ aws configure
>
> AWS Access Key ID : abc123
>
> AWS Secret Access Key [None]: def456
>
> Default region name [None]: us-west-2
>
> Default output format [None]:
>
> 9) I created an AMI using this EC2 with only the root device.

10) Terminated the EC2.

11) Launched a new EC2 from the AMI without additional volume and provided below inputs in user data section

> #!/bin/bash
>
> instanceid=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
>
> aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-abcd1234 --instance-id `echo instanceid` --device /dev/sdf
>
> sleep 20
>      mount -a

12) EC2 launches fine but Volume X is not getting attached to it.

> User data input:
>
> #!/bin/bash
>
> instanceid=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
>
> aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-abcd1234 --instance-id `echo
>
> $instanceid` --device /dev/sdf
>
> sleep 20
>
> mount -a

When I run the user inputs commands manually by connecting the EC2 through Putty, it is working perfectly and volume X is getting attached to the instance without any error. The volume X gets listed under df -h as well.

The expected result was, Volume X to get attached to the new EC2 instance automatically when launched through AMI. This is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had  same issue, and  here is  my working  example :

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(/usr/bin/curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
/usr/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume --region eu-central-1 --volume-id vol-volidhere --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdh
```

Yes, until I added the `--region`   nothing worked.
And I know  that aws configure --> default region is set (as it was mine ) but  here you go !